# Auto hide columns in Google Sheets based on date

Tags: google-sheets

I have a Google Sheet document where I use a date in each column for a whole year.
So in I2, J2, K2, L2, ... is always a date like in a Gantt chart. I want to hide all columns automatically if the date is before today().
Can this be done?

Comment: This is achievable using Google Apps Script, however to better understand your specific use case could you provide a sample sheet with a sample expected result?

Comment: Thank you for responding. Here is the sheet itself: [link]https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1J88qRxZPuYeC-D7ZsEq4Qw14WvdVeDie0Vm8LHk3QSE/edit?usp=sharing[/link]

As you can see, I now mark the current date with another color in row 2. While this is good, I also want the columns before that date to auto hide when opening the sheet.

Comment: Posted an answer with a sample code. Let me know if that works for you @diegie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following script:

```js
function onOpen() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Planning");
  var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+1", "dd/MM"); //Set your own timezone
  var range = sheet.getRange("I2:NI2");
  var dateRange = range.createTextFinder(date).findAll()[0];
  sheet.hideColumns(9, dateRange.getColumn()-9);
}
```

#### References:

- [hideColumns(columnIndex, numColumns)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#hidecolumnscolumnindex,-numcolumns)
- [Class TextFinder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/text-finder)

Comment: It works! Thank you very much. It's good that I know also understand the script so I could make some modifications for the future. Really appreciate it!

Comment: @diegie, If help you solve your question, you may click the accept button on the left (check icon). By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved. If the accept button is unavailable to you, you can review  "How to accept answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)"

Comment: I tagged it as accepted. Thanks again. One more questions regarding the script: is it also possible to hide all columns before today()-3 (so I see the 3 previous days before today still).

Comment: I got it. Never mind :-D